# Android Plugin/Application to store texts posted in social networks and resuse them

Tags: android, twitter, social-networking, facebook-android-sdk

I want to develop an app which will appear like a plugin when the user types something to a social network apps(comments or posts in facebook/tweets in twitter e.t.c). The app should appear as a handle so that the user will not be interrupted while using the social network. The app should be able to log the messages posted by the user and the user should be able to retrieve any logged texts from app so that he/she can reuse the same texts while posting.
Is it possible to implement such an app along with the social network app running? Kindly provide any links/ideas/design approaches....Waiting for your guidance..

Thanks,
Srooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to show a "handle" (unless you make a javascript plugin that runs on web browsers) but you can make the app I suppose. Here's one approach:

1. Create a web app that uses site-specific authentication and ask for permissions from all the social networks you plan to target.
2. Get permissions to read posts, comments, tweets etc using the site's API.
3. Periodically retrieve this stuff using the API from the sites and store them in your own server.
4. Write an android app that has a nice UI that retrieves this data for a particular user from your server (via your own REST API) and displays it in the mobile app.

This is a very high-level overview and the actual implementation is gonna be difficult and will take a while. But the basic approach should work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Anup..What if I need to log the texts while running social n/w apps(twitter,facebook native apps) instead of sites through browser?Please suggest..

Comment: you can set up your web server to periodically access the social network API's to get all the interactions the user has performed and save them to your server. Then the android app will access your server data and show it to the user.

Comment: Do we have to share the user's credentials to the application, if we want to store the texts from a particular user??

Comment: all these sites use OAuth 2.0 for authentication. The user will have to authorize your app and give it permissions to access your data. From then on, your app can access the user's data anytime unless the user revokes his permission.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anup..Seems this will stand as a seperate app. Is there any way so taht I can use this as part of the social n/w app..Because the requirement includes the facility to access this app without intruding the social n/w app for copying/reusing any stored texts..I'm bit new to Android..forgive my ignorance..        - Sruthy

Comment: no. It will have to be a separate app. Users can copy and paste text easily between apps in android. This feature is provided by the OS. Just make it into a separate app and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok Anup..Thanks for the guidance..I will check it and let you know.. -Sruthy